# Apache not generating access log. CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

For some reason, Apache is not generating logs in /var/log/httpd/access_log. How do I see if logging enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're piping to a program (like, e.g., cronolog), here's a handy trick for finding log files:

```
for pid in $(pidof httpd); do ls -l /proc/$pid/fd; done | awk '/^l/ {print $11}' | sort | uniq
```

If you are using a program like cronolog, just swap out "httpd" in favor of "cronolog" in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

This is presumably the same on Centos.

In each vhost file you can add:

`CustomLog /var/log/apache2/default_http_access_log combined`

That one above is for `001-default` the HTTP default vhost (not SSL) and I just change them per vhost and this is the catch all.

Comment: Otherwise check /var/log/httpd permissions.